# Difference between 怪我しました and 痛みがあります

Tags: word-choice

A bird was walking around and not flying away when approached.  I said:

> 鳥は痛みがあります。

What I said was corrected to:

> 鳥は怪我しました。

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

痛みがあります means "is in pain," whereas 怪我しました　means "is injured." A bird not flying is generally due to its inability to do so, in which case injury seems like a better explanation than discomfort (though it very well could also be in pain).

Comment: Please clarify for everyone if for "former" and "latter" you're referring to the order in the title or the order in the question.  Or just put which is which.

Comment: Didn't even realize they were ordered differently between the two. Fixed.